# Code markup plugin like the .wordpress.com blogs offer?

Tags: plugins

The free wordpress blogs (those hosted at wordpress.com) have a build in code formatting plugin

Is it possible to get this on private installs of wordpress? I've copied all my posts across but the code formatting feature doesn't work out of the box

I'm primarily looking for Java syntax highlighting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the plugin used on WordPress.com: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

Answer (score 3):

I use a plug-in called [Code Colorer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codecolorer/) that dynamically formats my code blocks and highlights syntax where appropriate.  I use it for PHP, C#, and JavaScript, but it also works for Java.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Code highlighter](http://ideathinking.com/wiki/index.php/WordPress:CodeHighlighterPlugin) plugin on my blog.

It is quote basic in case you do not need many controls hovering on your highlighted code when you hover on code.

Another I tried later is [Syntax Highlighter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/), same as suggested by [@sorich87](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/473/sorich87) above.

It is more colorful and provide many controls like copying code, printing, etc.